# iOS: Keyboard Close-Button missing

Tags: ios, maui

I am working with .NET MAUI (.NET 7) and show the App in iOS-Simulator for iOS 16.2

Currently, I am wondering why I do not see anything to close a Keyboard when I enter something to an Entry. Isn't there any Close-Button for the Keyboard on iOS or am I missing something? What is the philosophy there on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to add a close button to your keyboard.

The first way is to set the close style for the `ReturnType` of the `Ertry` tag, which will replace the `return` key with the `done` key as shown in the following image, you can refer to [Customize the return key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry#customize-the-return-key) for details.

[image]

The second way is to add a close button on top of the keyboard using customize control with handlers, as shown in the following image, you can refer to [MAUI-iOS-Keyboard-Done-Button](https://github.com/moraismateus/MAUI-iOS-Keyboard-Done-Button) for detailed steps.

[image]

Comment: Great response - I will try it this weekend and let you know :)

Comment: I tried the last solution as I think this could be more natural for a user. What I can see right now is just the small space with the "Done"-Button, but no Keyboard when I click in any of my Entrys. When I right-click on an Entry in my iOS-Simulator and explictly Show the Keyboard it shows up. When using the first approach with ```ReturnType="Done"```, I can't see the "done"-Label in case of a Numeric Keyboard. Are both observations normal?

Comment: Additionally, I have the issue that even when I am in a different language the English it is still „Done“ on the label